# Insert statement not working in foreach statement

Tags: php

I have a crawler which crawls the sites that begin with www.bbc.co.uk/news. It it grabs all the links that start with http://www.bbc.co.uk/news and finds their description, link and title and inserts them into a database.

For some reason, it doesn't seem to be inserting.

Any ideaS?

PS There is completely not output, completely blank web page

```
   foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output = array(
"title"       => Titles($link), //dont know what Titles is, variable or string?
"description" => getMetas($link),
"keywords" => getKeywords($link), 
"link"        => $link                 
 );
if (empty($output["description"])) {
$output["description"] = getWord($link);
 }

 if (substr($ouput, 0, 26) == "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/") {

 $data = '"' . implode('" , "', $output) . '"';
 $success = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO news_story (`title`, `description` , `keywords`, `link`)
 VALUES (" . $data . ")") or zerror_reporting();
 if ($sucess) {
echo "YEAH!";
   }

   if (!$sucess) {
echo "NO!!";
    }
    print_r($data);
     }}
```

Comment: Why not use their [feeds](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10628494)?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is Here:

```
 if (substr($ouput, 0, 26) == "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/") {

   $data = '"' . implode('" , "', $output) . '"';
  $success = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO news_story (`title`, `description` , `keywords`, `link`)
  VALUES (" . $data . ")") or zerror_reporting();
 if ($sucess) {
echo "YEAH!";
  }
```

Where is your `$ouput` variable...I think you wanted to write `$output`..but it also didnot execute because `$output` variable is a array not a `string`

Answer (score 0):

The blank white page is a PHP Fatal error that produces a `500 Internal Server Error` response. That is caused by this undefined function `zerror_reporting()`:

```
mysql_query(...) or zerror_reporting();
```

Change that to something like

```
mysql_query(...) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

The trigger_error() call will add the mysql error to your error log.

The second problem is you're trying to `substr()` on an array, you should be doing that on the `link` element:

```
 if (substr($output['link'], 0, 26) == "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanitization your value before inserting in to database

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @Mrinmoy is correct but there seems more issues in the code since your code never touched this further.

First set display errors:

```
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
foreach ($links as $link) {
```

PHP talks a lot, if you can listen.
I personally use E_ALL|E_STRICT but thats little too much for today. :)
Then sanitize your data or you would rarely succeed in inserting records. Your data will have lot of sentences:

```
 $output = array(
"title"       => mysql_real_escape_string(Titles($link)), //dont know what Titles is, variable or string?
"description" => mysql_real_escape_string(getMetas($link)),
"keywords" => mysql_real_escape_string(getKeywords($link)), 
"link"        => mysql_real_escape_string($link)                 
 );
if (empty($output["description"])) {
$output["description"] = mysql_real_escape_string(getWord($link));
 }
```

Then correct the variable typo and use the link index of the output array:

```
if (substr($output['link'], 0, 26) == "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/") {
```

At the end, if you still don't get data, you definitely will know much more to fix it yourself. And use `print_r($output); echo $data;` before calling mysql_query. Another way to  track progress by filling code with `echo __LINE__ . "\n";` to see where it died. Verify there is a method in your code by the name `zerror_reporting` or replace with `die(mysql_error());`